# `npm version patch` command failing

Tags: npm, npm-version

I am trying to patch a version of my Angular project using the command - 
`npm version patch` but getting an error -

`$ npm version patch
   npm ERR! npm version [<newversion> | major | minor | patch | premajor |    preminor | prepatch | prerelease [--preid=<prerelease-id>] | from-git]
   npm ERR! (run in package dir)
   npm ERR! 'npm -v' or 'npm --version' to print npm version (6.4.0)
   npm ERR! 'npm view <pkg> version' to view a package's published version
   npm ERR! 'npm ls' to inspect current package/dependency versions`

The same command used to work fine earlier and suddenly stopped working.
my npm version is 6.4.0.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was able to resolve the error by myself. The error was that the patch version was written as 01.
i.e. `2018.11.01` instead of `2018.11.1`. 
`npm version patch` failed without an explanatory message.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you're correct the **semver** version number must be a **valid integer from `[0-9]` inclusively**.

For reference, `npm` uses [node-semver](https://github.com/npm/node-semver#functions)  as their semver parser to deal with versioning on their end. Also, you mentioned the error failed silently, you need to *run your command with the verbose flag to see everything*.

For example, if you do a `npm version patch --verbose`, `npm` would spit out additional information for why the command failed. You can use the *verbose flag on any valid `npm` command*

Hopefully that helps!

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue with npm v6.14.8 and eventually discovered that I'd forgotten to include the `"version"` property in my package.json at all! This now works in [npm 7.0.9 and later](https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v7.0.9), but the change hasn't been backported to v6, so be sure you haven't left it out if you're still using that.